# Why does Allah bring hardship to animals?

Tags: day-of-judgement, animals, reward

If animals are not part of the test, why do they suffer from natural causes? And when on the Day of Judgment they'll be gathered to reclaim their rights over the oppressors, is it just their bodies that turn into dust or their souls too, thereby becoming non-existence?